# node.js pipe req to remote server and back to res: how to break pipe to res after res ends

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I'm using `express` and am trying to pipe a `req` to a remote server for processing and then pipe the result back to client via `res`.  It's working nicely, but occasionally I think that `res` is ended by the action of [`connect-timeout`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-timeout), resulting in a `write after end` error.

My code is presently along the following lines (I'm overdoing the logging for debug purposes):

```
var onErrorA = function (err) { console.log('error piping to destination:', err); };
var onErrorB = function (err) { console.log('error piping to res:', err); };
var onEndA = function () { console.log('pipe to destination ended'); };
var onEndB = function () { console.log('pipe to res ended'); };

var destination = request(destinationUrl);

req.pipe(destination)
    .on('error', onErrorA)
    .on('end', onEndA)
    .pipe(res)
    .on('error', onErrorB)
    .on('end', onEndB);
```

I see the following in the log:

```
error piping to res: Error: write after end 
pipe to destination ended
```

If I'm correct about what's going on, how do I "break" the pipeline (stop writing to `res`) once the `res` has been ended (timed out)?

I've tried something along the following lines, to try and catch when `res` has been ended (when `req.timedout` has been set to `true` by `connect-timeout`):

```
var destination = request(destinationUrl);

var readable = req.pipe(destination);
var onData = function (chunk) {
    if (req.timedout) {
        // prevent any further writing to res by unpiping it...
        readable.unpipe(res);
    }
};

// https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data
readable.on('data', onData);

readable.pipe(res);
```

But I just get the following error:

```
TypeError: readable.unpipe is not a function
```

Why is `unpipe` not a function of `readable`?

Any suggestions as to how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found an approach that works.  Not sure if it's the best approach, but it seems to work.  Any other answers with better ways of doing this would be interesting to see.

What I've done is to attach a listener to `res` for the `finish` event, and when that fires, I pause the readable stream from the destination, so that no further data is written to `res`:

```
var destination = request(destinationUrl);
var readable = req.pipe(destination);
var readableEnded = false;
readable.on('end', function () { readableEnded = true; });
readable.pipe(res);
res.on('finish', function () {
    if (!readableEnded) {
        readable.pause();
        destination.end();
    }
});
```